# using different programming language in godot game engine?

Tags: game-engine, godot

I want to **bind a different programming language to the Godot game engine**. Is there an instructional document or video on this topic? For example, how was this project done: [godot-rust](https://github.com/godot-rust/godot-rust). If I can learn the basics, I can succeed in working in a different language. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

*In this answer I show you the different approaches to add language support in Godot 3.x (the situation will be somewhat different with Godot 4.0 and GDExtension - which replaces GDNative and hopefully means less custom builds), and I mention some languages that are supported by each of these approaches. However, this is not an exhaustive list of the languages.*

---

First of all, Godot has official build-in support for **GDScript** and Godot's **VisualScript** (and Godot's shading language and its visual counterpart if those counts for you).

---

There are a few ways to use **C++**:

- You can use it to create GDNative scripts (which are basically a wrapper around native calls that allow you to use them as scripts in Godot).
- Or you can create modules (which are static libraries you can add in a custom Godot build).
- And since Godot source is in C++, you don't have to restrict yourself to making modules if you are making custom builds.

---

In web builds Godot can interface with **JavaScript** via the `JavaScript` class. However, this approach does not allow you to add JavaScript scripts to `Node`s, and so on.

---

Then there are languages that can only be added in custom builds of Godot, which is currently the official support for **C#**.

There are other non-official custom builds that offer language binding for languages such as **Lua**, **Kotlin**, **TypeScript** and **JavaScript** (this time allowing you to make scripts).

*If you need to add a runtime, you would probably do this.*

---

Some language take advantage of the fact that Godot's has official Mono support in order to support C#. This way you can, for example, use **F#** and **Clojure**.

*They start by adding a C# project and then modify it so it uses another language. This is viable if your language already compiles to .NET.*

---

Some other languages can be added as plugins that implement the `PluginScript` class via GDNative. This is the case of **Python** and **Lua** (again) which you can get from the asset library.

*This is the most user friendly way to add language support to Godot, but it is limited to what you can do with `PluginScript`.*

**Addendum**: Gil Barbosa Reis, author of the aforementioned Lua bindings, has an article series about its implementation stuffed away in the repository (in English and Portugueses): [godot-lua-pluginscript/extras/articles/](https://github.com/gilzoide/godot-lua-pluginscript/tree/main/extras/articles). It is probably the most comprehensive tutorial to date.

---

Other languages are added by means of taking advantage of GDNative (They basically mimic what you would do with C++). This is the case of **Nim**, **Rust**, **D**, **Haskell**, **Go**, **Swift**…

*So that's how godot-rust works: make native libraries using rust and the godot-rust create and add them as if they were made in C++. For any language for which there are the means to make native libraries already, this is a good option.*

---

Finally there is another way to add support for a language: a transpiler from that language to GDScript, which can be automated with an addon that might also be written in GDScript. This is the case of **Lisp**.

*This last approach is mostly used for domain specific languages.*

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.For example, when I want to bind the rust language to the godot game engine, how should I proceed? can you make a sample for me? It doesn't have to be with the rust language. It can also be python, ruby, dart, go.

Comment: @mrParabol I think it is probably best to begin by making GDNative libraries following the official docs: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdnative/what_is_gdnative.html. You are either going to implement a `PluginScript` that way, or convert it to a Godot module, or getting familiar with GDNative will help you later do the same in another language. Also, being familiar with the `EditorPlugin` (the same used for GDScript addons) might be useful. As for reference, you can look at some of the other languages bindings, see https://github.com/Vivraan/godot-lang-support/

Comment: thanks. I learned how to make a plugin by reading the documentation but I still couldn't find an example how to bind a new language. Until I learn it, I guess there will be no language left unadded :)

Comment: @mrParabol See addendum.

Answer (score 1):

The [official docs here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_languages.html) provide your answer:

Godot officially supports GDScript, C/C++, C#.

Some 3rd party languages that can be used are: Rust, D, Python, Nim, and Go.

Comment: How do they add (bind) 3rd party language? For example, how can I bind the crystal language to godot game engine?

Comment: You could use this module here: https://github.com/kalinon/godot-crystal. Bindings for this module specifically use a binding generator for C++ which is what Godot supports out of the box.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. My goal is not to use it, but to learn how to do it.  What is the method I should follow in this project? How is it done, can you give an example?